# .htaccess forcing https

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(register|login)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
```

I have several others that I need to force HTTPS like this:

http://www.mysite.com/inc/dues_login/ABC
http://www.mysite.com/inc/dues_login/DEF
http://www.mysite.com/inc/dues_login/GHI

How would I make these also forced to https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply extend your current condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(register|login|inc/dues_login)
```

This is assuming that any url starting with http://www.mysite.com/inc/dues_login should be forced to use https.

If you only want to redirect the specific paths you listed to https:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(register|login|inc/dues_login/ABC|inc/dues_login/DEF|inc/dues_login/GHI)
```

Comment: Actually had to do it like this: `^/(register|inc/dues_login/ABC|inc/dues_login/DEF...`

Comment: D'oh! I had missed the /inc/ part in your urls and just copy/pasted one in my answer. Of course that's what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the dues_login as a RewriteCond

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(register|login|dues_login)
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: That didn't work, see my comment on @brain99's answer.